# Pointing bundler to local fork besides master branch?

Tags: ruby, git, bundle, bundler

I was looking into what options there were for pointing bundler/Gemfile to local forks of repos and came across ["Local Git Repositories"](http://bundler.io/git.html#local) on the bundler.io site but it appears since you have to specify a branch, if you're working off a specific feature branch such as `ticket###-some-task` then you would have to go into the Gemfile and update the `branch:` parameter to point to that instead otherwise bundler will complain that a different branch is checked out.

Is there a simpler way to point at a feature branch if you're working on 2 or more projects at the same time? Here's an example:

```
# project-1 Gemfile  
gem 'project-2', git: 'git@local.repo.com:org/project-2', branch: 'master'

# project-2 is checked out to a branch called 'new-changes'
```

I then run: `bundle config local.project-2 /path/to/project-2`

Do I have to go into `project-1` Gemfile and change the `branch` to `new-changes` every time I encounter something like this? Then when I'm done with the code change in `project-2` and it's been merged into `master`, I would have to remember to go back into the `Gemfile` and change `new-changes` back to `master`?

It seems like you could run into the issue where developers would forget to change the branch back to `master` in the `project-1` Gemfile?

Comment: Wouldn't `bundle config disable_local_branch_check true` mentioned in the doc ,fix the issue ?

Comment: Also, this doesn't really answer your question (sorry...), but it sounds like your projects are tightly coupled; have you considered decoupling or merging them?